# How to convert to unsigned long from 4 char array?

Tags: avr, conversion

I am programming an AVR chip (atmega1284p) with c code, I am using SPI to read in 4 bytes from a chip on my circuit. I would like to take those 4 bytes and return them as an unsigned long.

I can print the bytes to the serial port and I have received logical values, which I can calculate by hand to get the correct value. I then try to do this with programming and I get very peculiar results. Here is the code snippet.

Note: returnBytes is a 4 character array with the correct character values. Also, I am using a bitmask to make sure that the shift doesn't have anything weird going on -- just incase (works the same with and without bitmask).

```
unsigned long returnLong = (returnBytes[3]&0xFF)<<24;
returnLong |= (returnBytes[2]&0xFF)<<16;
returnLong |= (returnBytes[1]&0xFF)<<8;
returnLong |= (returnBytes[0]&0xFF);

return returnLong;
```

What I get from this is peculiar, in that it should be counting from 4.2bil to 0. It starts at around 4.2 bil, generally counts down and then drops to 30,000 after a couple of counts, then jumps back to 4.2bil after a couple of counts. (Yes the counter will wrap back around once it hits 0).

I am certain that the bytes are correct and my method of printing the unsigned long is correct.

Here is the output of this code (First line is bytes 3 2 1 0, Second line is the value of the unsigned long)

```
255 254 230 157
Counter Value: 4294960797
255 253 206 25
Counter Value: 4294954521
255 252 182 90
Counter Value: 4294948442
255 251 158 153
Counter Value: 4294942361
255 250 134 159
Counter Value: 4294936223
255 249 110 139
Counter Value: 28299
255 248 87 207
Counter Value: 22479
255 247 65 170
Counter Value: 16810
```

Hopefully this is enough info.

Comment: Just create a UNION in c.  Read the bytes in as bytes, and addres the long as a long.  No conversions necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible answers to this as a processor can be *bigendian* meaning that the byte with the lowest address is the most significant or *littlendian* meaning that this byte is the least significant.

I'll assume the the bytes are stored in an array

```
unsigned char a[4];
```

and we want the result in

```
unsigned long retval;
```

If the system is bigendian

```
retval  = (unsigned long) a[0] << 24 | (unsigned long) a[1] << 16;
retval |= (unsigned long) a[2] << 8 | a[3];
```

If the system is littlendian

```
retval  = (unsigned long) a[3] << 24 | (unsigned long) a[2] << 16;
retval |= (unsigned long) a[1] << 8 | a[0];
```

Note the casts are necessary because otherwise you lose bits.  For example

```
retval = a[0] << 8;
```

Should always be zero assuming that an unsigned char is 8 bit because

```
a[0] << 8
```

Will shift all 8 bits out of the 8 bit variable and they will be lost be lost because the compiler is doing 8 bit arithmetic. The resulting answer 0 will then be written into the 32bit long.

Having the cast changes the number in a[0] into a 32bit value first so the shift does not lose these bits.

Comment: I continued working on this after asking the question and I figure out what the problem was -- your note hits it exactly. My chip is littlendian, so that is all correct, however the cast was my problem. I figured out that when I shifted, it dumps the bits because the char is only 8 bits. I added casts and it works perfectly, thanks.